# Azure file share not persisting

Tags: azure, azure-files

I've got a storage account in Azure that I made a network drive on my PC. It seems as if the drive I configure does not maintain connectivity for very long. 
It feels as if every time I reboot, I have to remove the drive and reconnect to Azure.
Is there some configuration I'm missing for this?

Comment: How are you mapping the network drive - through Windows Explorer or by using `net use` command or something else?

Comment: Interchanging between net use and powershell.

Comment: For `net use` can you try with `/p:yes` option and for PowerShell can you try with `-persist` and see if that helps? https://www.lifewire.com/net-use-command-2618096 (for net use command).

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Azure file share in windows, you can persist the mount with the document  [Persisting Azure file share credentials in Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows#persisting-azure-file-share-credentials-in-windows) here. If in Linux, follow the document [Create a persistent mount point for the Azure file share with /etc/fstab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux#create-a-persistent-mount-point-for-the-azure-file-share-with-etcfstab) here.

Comment: If the answer is helpful to you or for more help, please tell me.